# How can I remove an inline onclick attribute with a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, bookmarklet

There is an annoying website out there that foils attempts to "open in new tab" by using `<div onclick=>` instead of `<a href=>`. I've written a bookmarklet, using jQuery, that creates a wrapper `<a>` tag and inserts it within the `<div>` around its content.

How can I remove the original `onclick` handler?

Comment: What about just stopping the click from propagating up to the div with `event.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: What is the original click handler doing? Can you elaborate on "foiling attempts"?

Comment: The page is using the `onclick` attribute to link to another page, rather than using an `a` tag.

Answer (score 5):

Not mentioned yet:

```
$('#myId')[0].onclick = null; // remove the inline onclick() event
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but...

```
$("selector").removeAttr("onclick");
```

I guess you have already tried to

```
$("selector").unbind("click");
```

Comment: Neither seemed to work. I also tried
`$("selector").attr("onclick",function(){})`

Comment: The first example here worked for me.  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div').removeAttr('onclick');        
    });

Answer (score 1):

In some circumstances setting `onclick` to `null` won't work, but this should always work:

```js
document.getElementById("myId").setAttribute("onclick", "");
```