# Before submitting form programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

In jQuery-Mobile I'm submitting a form programmatically and I want to capture the submit event to perform some validations before. I have already tried the following solution provided in other questions about jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#my_form').bind('submit', function() {
    alert('before submit');

    ...

  });
});
```

But I cannot get the function executed and the alert displayed. Does anyone know any other way to achieve this?

My form is something like:

```
<form id="my_form" method="POST" action="..." data-theme="b">
```

And the way I am calling it programmatically, from another section of the same page is like this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="document.forms['my_form'].submit(); return false;" value="Submit" data-theme="b"/>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is it a misspell here only that you have spelled value *vakue* in your `<input type="submit"...` ?

Comment: Yes, it's only a misspell here. In my original code it's correct and the form is correctly submitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The submit handler of the form is NOT executed when you submit the form programatically.

NOTE: Do NOT use a submit button to programatically submit a form. Instead use button or allow the submission from the submit button to be handled, i.e.

`<input type="button" onclick="document.forms['my_form'].submit()" value="Submit another form" data-theme="b"/>`

(the above is not correct anyway since it needs the form to have a NAME, not just an ID)

So

`<input type="button" onclick="document.forms['my_form_NAME'].submit()" value="Submit another form" data-theme="b"/>`

OR

`<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('my_form_ID').submit()" value="Submit another form" data-theme="b"/>`

OR since you have jQuery:

`<input type="button" onclick="$('#my_form_ID'].submit()" value="Submit another form" data-theme="b"/>`

OR if you can put the button in the form (best way):

`<input type="submit" value="Submit THIS form" data-theme="b"/>`

But since you want to bind - here is how to submit using another button instead of the better way using the form's own submit button:

```
<form id="actualForm">...
.
.

</form>


<input type="button" id="subbut" value="Submit another form on this page" data-theme="b"/>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#subbut').bind('click', function() {
    alert('before submit');

    ...

    $("#actualForm").submit();
  });
});
```

If there is hardcoded inline behaviour you cannot change, use the jQuery to remove it too

[How can I remove an inline onclick attribute with a bookmarklet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562159/how-can-i-remove-an-inline-onclick-attribute-with-a-bookmarklet)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#subbut').attr('onclick',""); // or $('#subbut').onclick=null;
  $('#subbut').bind('click', function() {
    alert('before submit');

    ...

    $("#actualForm").submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: I would like to ask you too, do you know another way to do so without having to modify the submission code? Is not there any other way only "capturing" the submission event or something similar? Thank you.

Comment: Depends. If the submission code is WRONG, then you have to replace the code - see update

Comment: Whoever downvoted this without comment has misunderstood the reason votes exist. Completely useless action without a reason why

Answer (score -1):

Changing the return value of onClick to TRUE does the job:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="document.forms['my_form'].submit(); return ***true***;" vakue="Submit" data-theme="b"/>
```

Comment: It's still ignoring the function for me.

Comment: Wrong form - and it is VERY bad practice to submit a form programtically from its own submit button or onsubmit

Comment: As correctly pointed out by @mplungjan, its a bad practice to do so. You can make it as type = "button" and use the onClick functionality to call a function inside a script and inside that function you can do a form submit.