# Need help running this Javascript code on Internet Explorer 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I am running the following JavaScript Bookmarklet code  in Chrome and it's running perfectly fine. However, only a blank window opens when I try the same code in IE.

```
javascript:var str=document.documentElement.innerHTML;
var find='</textarea>';var re=RegExp(find,'g');str=str.replace(re,"</OMG>");
var cmrform = document.createElement("form");cmrform.target="CMRWindow";cmrform.method="POST";
cmrform.action="http://localhost:8080/cmr/CMRTool.jsp";
 var srcInput=document.createElement("input");srcInput.type="text";srcInput.name="sourceCode";srcInput.value=str;cmrform.appendChild(srcInput);CMRWindow=window.open("","CMRWindow","status=0,title=0,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1");cmrform.submit();
```

Can someone please guide me why this code is not working in IE.

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: Try deleting `srcInput.type="text";` - older IE doesn't like you changing the type of an input after it's created, and "text" is the default type for inputs anyway.

Comment: If I remember correctly, IE security restrictions prevent submitting a form without [user interaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294195/before-submitting-form-programmatically).

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.forms` instead of `cmrform`:

```
document.forms[document.forms.length - 1].submit();
```