# Disabling onclick attribute with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, onclick

How do I disable the other onclick event once one of them has been activated. Both divs are set to display:none; in the CSS. This is probably really simple but I am new to programming.

HTML

```
<a id="leftbutton" href="#" onclick="showDiv(this.id); return false;">click me</a>
<a id="righttbutton" href="#"onclick="showDiv(this.id); return false;">click me</a>
```

Javascript

```
function showDiv(id)
{   
  if(id == "leftbutton"){
     document.getElementById('orangediv').style.display = 'block';
     }else{
     document.getElementById('greendiv').style.display = 'block';
}}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Remove onclick event from img tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712219/remove-onclick-event-from-img-tag) and technically of [How can I remove an inline onclick attribute with a bookmarklet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562159/how-can-i-remove-an-inline-onclick-attribute-with-a-bookmarklet) as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
function showDiv(id)
{   
  if(id == "leftbutton"){
     document.getElementById('orangediv').style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById('righttbutton').onclick = null;
     }else{
     document.getElementById('greendiv').style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById('leftbutton').onclick = null;
}}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this one first and it did what I was trying to do before.

Answer (score 0):

Like this for example:

```
function showDiv(id){   

  if  (id == "leftbutton"){
  document.getElementById('orangediv').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('rightbutton').onclick = "#";
}else{
  document.getElementById('greendiv').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('leftbutton').onclick = "#";
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
function showDiv(id){   
var o = document.getElementById('orangediv');
var g = document.getElementById('greendiv');
if  (id == "leftbutton"){
     o.style.display = 'block';
}else{
    g.style.display = 'block';
}
o.writeAttribute('onclick','');
g.writeAttribute('onclick','');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the onclick property of the other element to null;

```
if  (id == "leftbutton"){
        document.getElementById('orangediv').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('righttbutton').onclick = null;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('greendiv').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('leftbutton').onclick = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function showDiv(id) {
    if ( showDiv.executed ) {
        return false;
    }

    if  ( id === "leftbutton" ) {
       document.getElementById('orangediv').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
       document.getElementById('greendiv').style.display = 'block';
    }

    showDiv.executed = true;
}

showDiv.executed = false;
```

Doing it this way, you could always re-enable the showing by simply setting `showDiv.executed` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You could test if the other element is displayed :

```
function showDiv(id)
{ 
  if  (id == "leftbutton" && (document.getElementById('greendiv').style.display == 'none'))
  {
      document.getElementById('orangediv').style.display = 'block';
  }
  else if(id == "rightbutton" && (document.getElementById('orangediv').style.display == 'none'))
  {
      document.getElementById('greendiv').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the href attribute as id of div which should be visibled after you click.
`showDiv` function can get entire element as argument, then you have access to it  attributes as well. Second argument can be a id of element you should hide,

```
   <a id="leftbutton" href="orangediv" onclick="showDiv(this,'rightbutton');return false">click me</a>
   <a id="righttbutton" href="greendiv"onclick="showDiv(this,'leftbutton');return false">click me</a>
```

And in js:

```
var showDiv =function(el, toHide){
  document.getElementById( el.href ).style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById( toHide ).style.display = 'none';
  el.onclick = null; //remove onclick declaration from this anchor.

}
```